# Syntax not clear about pointers and matrix

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, libpng

i am coding in C and i have to work with png images, so i work with `libpng` library. In my project i use this structure:

```
png_bytep *row_pointers; /* <-- to declare the pointer that will contain the image 
                           and this to initialize the pointer to contain the image. */

row_pointers = (png_bytep*)malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * height); 
for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    row_pointers[y] = (png_byte*)malloc(png_get_rowbytes(png,info)); 
}
```

My problem is: after this piece of code my image is copyed in row_pointers and i want to copy it in a `png_byte map[x][y]` so i can work easly pixel for pixel. 
Someone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `row_pointers ` is not a double pointer?

Comment: no, i am not. I've copyed this part of the code and that's the reason of my dubts.
PS:
if it is a double pointer, how could i copyed it in another simpler stucture to manage?

Comment: @haccks `png_bytep` the `p` at the end indicates it is a byte poniter. So it is correct. He has to remove his cast at every malloc. It is not needed in C.

Comment: removing every cast should be this:
    row_pointers = malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * height); 
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        row_pointers[y] = malloc(png_get_rowbytes(png,info)); 
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. That is pointer to pointer!

`png_bytep`  = pointer to `png_byte`

If you eliminate `png_bytep` and just use `png_byte` your code will look like this.

```
int height = 10;
int width = 20;

png_byte **row_pointers;
row_pointers = (png_byte**)malloc(sizeof(png_byte*) * height);  <-- This is basically your number of rows.. ie height of your matrix.
for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
{
    row_pointers[y] = (png_byte*)malloc(sizeof(png_byte)*width); <-- This is representing number of elements in each row.. so width. 

}
```

Assuming your structure have two ints x and y. you must be filing data as below..

```
for(int i=0;i< height;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<width;j++)
    {
        row_pointers[i][j].x = i*j;
        row_pointers[i][j].y = i*j;
    }
}
```

Assuming your map also have similar structure. This is how you copy data..

```
for(int i=0;i< height;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<width;j++)
    {
        map[i][j].x = row_pointers[i][j].x;
        map[i][j].y = row_pointers[i][j].y;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code accomplishes nothing. It is the same as the original code. Only the name typedef's have been replaced by their original types...

Comment: His (hidden) question is: How do i get `row_pointers`/`map` to contain my images pixels?

Comment: clear, but modifying my code in this way after how can i assign `row_pointers`to `map[x][y]` ( because the point is at the end to be able to show every pixel using map[x][y] ( or something like that)

Comment: Err.. his main subject line question is syntax not clear. so I tried to explain how it is..

Comment: yes. I'll try immediatly to use this code. Assuming only an int variable x, after the inizialize, could i print map with
`printf("map[i][j]=%d",map[i][j].x)`
correct?

Comment: yes! That's correct. I have corrected one typo. please take new code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at pnm2png.c in libpng's contrib/pngminus directory.

In this code, "png_pixels" is a simple array that holds all the pixels, and row_pointers is an array of pointers that point to the beginning of each row within png_pixels:

```
/* row_bytes is the width x number of channels x (bit-depth / 8) */
  row_bytes = width * channels * ((bit_depth <= 8) ? 1 : 2);

  png_pixels = (png_byte *) malloc (row_bytes * height * sizeof (png_byte))

/* set the individual row_pointers to point at the correct offsets */
  for (i = 0; i < (height); i++)
    row_pointers[i] = png_pixels + i * row_bytes;

/* now we can go ahead and just read the whole image */
  png_read_image (png_ptr, row_pointers);
```

Once png_read_image completes, you can easily work with your pixels in the png_pixels array.

Notice that there is only one "malloc", which allocates png_pixels.  Instead of doing a separate "malloc" for each row, this code calculates the values of the row_pointers.

Comment: it seems a good tip, thanks. I will try to use it too. But in channels i have already the number of that or i have to set that variable?

Comment: Channels can be 1, 2, 3, or 4, depending upon the PNG color type.  You can get the number of channels with "png_get_channels(png, png_info);".  Also, if it's possible that you might be reading 16-bit samples, you need to account for that.  See the libpng/contrib/pngminus example that I mentioned earlier.